# How should I pass data to mxArray *plhs[] of mexFunction in order to get its outputs in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, visual-studio, visual-c++, mex, matlab-compiler

I want to have a precompiled function that returns the maximum positive real root of a quadratic equation if it has any positive roots and if not returns 0.   I'm working with some remote sensing data and I have done some tests and now all of the quadratic polynomials in my case have real roots but can't be sure about their sign. So I have written the following C source code.

```
/*
 * mx_solve_quadratic.cpp
 *
 * Solves for real roots of the standard quadratic equation
 *
 * The calling syntax is:
 *
 *      MaxRoot = mx_solve_quadratic(coefficientMatrix)
 *
 * This is a MEX file for MATLAB.
*/


#include <math.h>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"



int gsl_poly_solve_quadratic (double , double , double , double *, double *);

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  double a; /* coefficient for x^2 */
  double b; /* coefficient for x */
  double c; /* coefficient for 1 */
  double x0; /* the smaller root */
  double x1; /* the bigger root */
  double *inMatrix = NULL;
  inMatrix = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
  a = inMatrix[0];
  b = inMatrix[1];
  c = inMatrix[2];
  int i = gsl_poly_solve_quadratic(a,b,c,&x0,&x1);
  double signRoot = (x1 > 0 ? x1 : 0);
  mxSetPr(plhs[0], &signRoot);
}


int gsl_poly_solve_quadratic (double a, double b, double c, double *x0, double *x1)
{
  if (a == 0) /* Handle linear case */
    {
      if (b == 0)
        {
          return 0;
        }
      else
        {
          *x0 = -c / b;
          return 1;
        };
    }

  {
    double disc = b * b - 4 * a * c;

    if (disc > 0)
      {
        if (b == 0)
          {
            double r = sqrt (-c / a);
            *x0 = -r;
            *x1 =  r;
          }
        else
          {
            double sgnb = (b > 0 ? 1 : -1);
            double temp = -0.5 * (b + sgnb * sqrt (disc));
            double r1 = temp / a ;
            double r2 = c / temp ;

            if (r1 < r2) 
              {
                *x0 = r1 ;
                *x1 = r2 ;
              } 
            else 
              {
                *x0 = r2 ;
                  *x1 = r1 ;
              }
          }
        return 2;
      }
    else if (disc == 0) 
      {
        *x0 = -0.5 * b / a ;
        *x1 = -0.5 * b / a ;
        return 2 ;
      }
    else
      {
        return 0;
      }
  }
}
```

In fact I want `signRoot` be returned to MATLAB as a scalar value.  I've debugged the code two times:

```
a=[1 3 2];
b=mx_solve_quadratic(a)
```

[image]

```
a=[1 -3 2];
b=mx_solve_quadratic(a)
```

[image]

I see everything is OK until the last line, where I want to pass `signRoot` as the output. If I press `F10`, I'll get the error:

[image]

Or if I try to run the mex function in MATLAB without debugging, I'll get:

[image]

Comment: You're allocating an array in C and then trying to hand it off to MATLAB. Instead, you want to allocate memory in MATLAB (using an `mxCreate*` function) and then fill this array.

Comment: @Suever thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suever is correct.  You are trying to pass an array created in C and handing it off to MATLAB which is ill-advised and undefined behaviour.  What you must do instead is use any of the `mxCreate*` functions and set the memory locations to whatever results you want.  The easiest would be to use [`mxCreateDoubleMatrix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatedoublematrix.html) and specify that the output has 1 row, 1 column (i.e. a scalar) and ensure that the output is real.

Therefore, do something like this to replace the last line of code in your `mexFunction`:

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
double *out = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
*out = signRoot;
```

This first allocates memory on the MATLAB side for a single scalar.  You then get a pointer to this memory, then set it accordingly.

To be absolutely sure we're on the same page, here's what the `mexFunction` would look like after modification. Note that the lines that are changed are referenced with the `/* NEW */` comment.

```
/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  double a; /* coefficient for x^2 */
  double b; /* coefficient for x */
  double c; /* coefficient for 1 */
  double x0; /* the smaller root */
  double x1; /* the bigger root */
  double *inMatrix = NULL;
  inMatrix = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
  a = inMatrix[0];
  b = inMatrix[1];
  c = inMatrix[2];
  int i = gsl_poly_solve_quadratic(a,b,c,&x0,&x1);
  double signRoot = (x1 > 0 ? x1 : 0);
  plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL); /* NEW */
  double *out = mxGetPr(plhs[0]); /* NEW */
  *out = signRoot; /* NEW */
}
```

---

Running the above code with your two example inputs now gives:

```
>> a = [1 -3 2];
>> b = mx_solve_quadratic(a)

b =

     2

>> a = [1 3 2];
>> b = mx_solve_quadratic(a)

b =

     0
```